# Visual Basic Database program not running on other machines

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, installation, runtime

I have a database application I've made with Visual basic using Data source tables ext.
When I run the program on my machine, it works beautifully, but after publishing it and attempting to run the program on other machines, it gives a large error box; this is what I remember it showing :

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to a SQL Server
>       Unable to Locate a Local database runtime installation"

After googling this I got hold of an installation package to assist : SqlLocaLDB.MSI "SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB"

This resolved the issue with the error popping up, but what I was hoping to do was add and remove lines to the database with the use of my VB program, and access it across multiple machines.

I have a network drive, what do I need to do to allow the program to access the data from my network drive and save back to it, and have different machines use the program from the same database file?

Answer (score 0):

When databases are deployed they are often 'split' so the tables and data are in one file (the backend) and the queries, forms, etc are in another file (the front end).

It is this latter file that is installed on client machines while the backend with the actual tables and data reside on some other machine on the network.
then the 'front end' has to be 'connected' to the back-end so it knows where the data is located on the network.

If you wrote this database from scratch using Visual Basic (as opposed to using Microsoft Access and VBA) then I'm not sure how you split the front-end from the back-end.

If you just copy the entire program along with the related tables and data to each machine you will have a problem as each machine has it's own version of the data.

Try to Google how to split a Visual Basic database into a front end and back end... then Google how to 'connect' the front end on a client machine to the back end on the machine that will be containing the data file.

Hope this gives you some ideas of what to look for and where to begin.